# How to add exception handling in this code of PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, error-handling

***Apply exception handling using try-catch for System.OutOfMemoryException***

**Here is the current code:**

I am new to PowerShell and I am not sure where the try-catch is supposed to go in this code.
Is it supposed to encompass the entire code?

```bsh
# This forces the user to choose a value 1-5, a certain output is returned 
# depending on number choice
while ($true) {
    $input = Read-Host "Enter the option 1-5"
    if ($input -eq 5) {
        break
    }
    switch ( $input ) {
        # Gets current date and time
        1 {
            $temp = Get-Date
            $answer = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "[A-Z,a-z,0-9]*[.][l][o][g]" }
            echo $temp $answer
            echo $temp $answer >> DailyLog.txt
        }
        # Lists files
        2 {
            $answer = Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property name | select name
            echo $answer
            echo $answer >> C916contents.txt
        }
        # Lists current CPU processing percentage and memory usage
        3 {
            Get-Counter -Counter '\Process(_total)\% Processor Time' -MaxSamples 4 -SampleInterval 5
            Get-Counter -Counter '\\desktop-l8dtt4r\physicaldisk(_total)\current disk queue length' -MaxSamples 4 -SampleInterval 5
        }
        # Gets current running procces on PC
        4 {
            Get-Process | Sort-Object -Property cpu
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you running in this script that causes OutofMemoryException ?

Comment: There is nothing that throws this error but the assignment needs me to put in a try-catch exception in case that error does happen. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I believe it would be when the user selects "3" as the input due to how long it takes to retrieve the information. But because the -MaxSamples is set to 4, it won't exhaust all the memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 cases and most of the cases would not cause the System.OutOfMemoryExceptions. When you are dealing with Get-Content or Get-ChildItems, there is likely a chance that you will read so much data that script will throw System.OutOfMemoryException. But the choices 1 and 2 only read certain folders only, nothing recursive about them so getting System.OutOfMemoryException is less likely to occur.

choice 4 also reads in a the processes of the system and sorts it based on CPU. Does not use up much Memory to throw the exception either.

Choice 3 is interesting but the fact that it only gets the counters and doesnt store anything would not seem that it would cause any system.OutOfMemoryException either.

I ran all 4 scenarios and none of them cause any issues related to memory.

I would recommend encompassing the entire switch statement with the try / catch block with System.OutOfMemoryException as you are running the entire switch inside a while loop. It could be either of the choices that could cause the error.

```
  try {
    switch ( $input ) {
      # Gets current date and time
      1 {
        $temp= Get-Date
        $answer = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "[A-Z,a-z,0-9]*[.][l] 
        [o][g]" }
        echo $temp $answer
        echo $temp $answer >> DailyLog.txt
      }
      # Lists files
      2 {
        $answer = Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property name | select name
        echo $answer
        echo $answer >> C916contents.txt
      }
      # Lists current CPU processing percentage and memory usage
      3 {    
        Get-Counter -Counter '\Process(_total)\% Processor Time' -MaxSamples 4 -SampleInterval 5
        Get-Counter -Counter '\\desktop-l8dtt4r\physicaldisk(_total)\current disk queue length' -MaxSamples 4 -SampleInterval 5
      }
      # Gets current running procces on PC
      4 {
        Get-Process | Sort-Object -Property cpu
      }
    }
  }
  Catch [System.OutOfMemoryException] {
    Write-Output "OutOfMemoryException occured."
  }
  Catch {
    Write-OUtput "Something else happened: $($_.Exception.Message)"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I appreciate it. I don't know too much of PowerShell to answer why they want to me to run a try-catch.

Comment: It won't allow me because I do not have enough reputation I guess.

Comment: @TheScarecrow there should be a check mark to mark the post as answer